# Problem looping through files in directory while checking database with Python

Tags: python, mysql, file

I'm trying to process a bunch of csv files in a given directory.  Each time I run the script, it goes through each file in the directory (in case I've added new ones), and then checks agains the database to see if the file has been processed, and if so, what line to start processing from.

Problem is, the script seems to skip any file I have listed in the database table, regardless of what the status is.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but can't quite piece together where my tests are going wrong.

Here's the structure of the table:

```
file_processed_id | file_type | file_name | file_line | file_lines_processed | file_lines_skipped | file_status
```

Here's the pertinent code:

```
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    status = check_process_status(filename,conn)
    if status != None:
        if status[7] == 'completed':
            pass
        else:
            start_line = status[3]
            file_to_processed = filename
            break
    else:
        start_line = 0
        file_to_be_processed = filename
```

And here's the function checking the db:

```
def check_process_status(f,conn):

    # retrieve process status of file

    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""SELECT *
                FROM files_processed
                WHERE file_type = 'faca'
                AND file_name = %s
                """,(f,))

    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row == None:
        return None # if no entry, returns null
    else:
        return row # returns row information
```

I've tested the db connection and everything, and if the file actually exists in the table, it returns the row information just fine.  The thing I don't get is why it's skipping to the next file each time I run the script, no matter what the "file_status" field is set to.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why is there a `break` in the loop?

Comment: Well, I'm probably missing something terribly basic, but this loop is separate from the loop where I cycle through the csv file, so once I find a file that hasn't been processed, I need to set the variables and break out of the loop.

Comment: When it gets to the `break`, it will not process another file.  It will appear to skip every file after the one that leads to the `break`.  Is that what you intend?  If so, your question is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, oughtn't there be a `break` statement in the `else` clause after `file_to_be_processed = filename` too?

Also note that this variable is misnamed `file_to_processed` a few lines above.

Also note that `status[7]` will probably throw an exception, since there only appear to be 7 fields in your table. I'd guess it should be `status[6]`.